# Query for a row in a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have this code:

```
X = tfidf.fit_transform(data['Content']) # the matrix articles x max_features(=words)
dense = X.toarray()
print dense[432]
```

and the output is:

```
[ 0.          0.          0.45446165  0.          0.22281507  0.
  0.27551889  0.37350294  0.          0.72691331]
```

Can I ask the matrix in the opposite direction, i.e. which is the index of this row?

---

I could obviously make a for loop and search manually for the row.

Comment: Have you tried `dense.index(...)` ?

Comment: You mean knowing the row? In the dense case it is quite simple with `(np.where((dense == row).all(axis=1)))`

Comment: @Scony no, since I am really new in Python and I do not know the capabilities of it. However the answer works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to work with dense matrices then it is a simple array comparison, for example

```
np.where((dense == row).all(axis=1))[0]
```

Comment: What does the result `[   21  7358 10896 23606]` means? That it finds the `row` we are looking for in these four indices?

Comment: Probably. Check by looking at `dense[[21, 7358, ...]]`

Comment: I am going to index the matrix with a list? I was thinking about dense[21], then dense[7358]..